# I want to add two application name in manifest

Tags: java, android, google-analytics, android-manifest

I want to include these two application in my android manifest file . It can only include one name not two. One application name is built i and other is an java class. Kindly helpme to solve it.

```
 <application
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    android:name=".GoogleAnalyticsApplication"
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your AppController class extend Analytics application class. Then specify your AppController in the manifest.

Answer (score -1):

You can extend `MultiDexApplication` in your `GoogleAnalyticsApplication` like below

```
public class GoogleAnalyticsApplication extends MultiDexApplication 
{

}
```

And in Mainfest you can specify only your class name

```
<application
    android:name=".GoogleAnalyticsApplication"
</application>
```